# jquery event not registering

Tags: jquery, events

I have an image which I have a click event attached to, which works fine if I go

```
$('#image-id').click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
});
```

my problem is if I go

```
$.myGlobals = {
   id : $('#image-id')
};
var mg = $.myGlobals;

mg.id.click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
});
```

the second method doesn't work at all, but if I try getting an attribute using say
`mg.id.attr('title');`
it returns fine, its only the events that wont work.

Comment: Your code works for me in the Chrome console, are you sure there isn't something else you're overlooking?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/et7mc/

Comment: Make sure you define $.myGlobals when document is fully loaded. I.e. at the bottom of the body or in $(function() { }) wrapper.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. it appears to be to do with a callback I am using when a div is shown that contains the image. What's strange is that I could return the attributes of the image fine but the click wasn't working. The fix was to set the id of the image inside the document ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you added button after document has been loaded. You can try to use live instead bind.

```
mg.id.live('click', function() {
   alert('clicked');
});
```